# How to test Isabelle proof from archieve list

Tags: functional-programming, logic, isabelle

From [Archieve of Isabelle Proofs](https://www.isa-afp.org/)  if one wants to test [AVL Tree](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/AVL-Trees.shtml), how to go about it? 
Proof is there and gets approved by Isabelle Ide as well but what to test and how?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "testing"?

Comment: @larsrh: I mean what to do with this proof? How to use it and test what?

Comment: Sorry, but this is still unclear. What do you want to do with this AFP entry? Generate executable code to include AVL trees in your program?

Comment: @larsrh: Lets take `height_mkt_bal_` , is it about just checking if its true or there are other things one can do?

Comment: Well, those are lemmas, so if they are checked in Isabelle/jEdit, then they're true. No further checking needed.